# Assertion failed in imread() function

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to do a simple template matching with openCV-python, but right in the beginning getting an error.
I've run the following code:

````
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


haystackImg = cv.imread('fullImage.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
needleImg = cv.imread('diamond.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

result = cv.matchTemplate(haystackImg,needleImg, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

cv.imshow('result', result)
cv.waitKey() ```
````

...and I got this error:

```
[ WARN:0@0.186] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('fullImage.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
[ WARN:0@0.195] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('diamond.png'): can't open/read 
file: check file path/integrity                                                                                                                                 ython39/python.exe "c:/U
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[myFilePath]\starting.py", line 8, in <modd file: check file path/ule>
    result = cv.matchTemplate(haystackImg,needleImg, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:588: error: (-215:Assertion failed) corr.rows <= img.rows + 
templ.rows - 1 && corr.cols <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'cv::crossCorr'
```

The confusing part of it, that I didn't even have a D: drive, and the module is searching for something on that. I reinstalled it, but it didn't help.

Comment: The D drive/path is not related to your machine, it is the drive on which opencv C++ code was compiled. From the error your reported it seems you image file is either corrupted or not saved at the location you provided to OpenCv. You should try to pass an absolute path to the image (not a relative one).

Comment: your template is bigger than the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that my source path contained non ASCII characters such as á and é... Created a new location without any non ASCII characters and white-spaces, and it works fine now.